# How to call parent's method which is overloaded in child

Tags: php, class, parent, superclass, super

I have PHP code

```
<?
class AParent {

  function to_s() {
    return $this->id;
  }

}

class AChild {

  public $id;
  public $name;

  function to_s() {
    if(!empty($this->name)) {
      $ret = $this->name;
    } else {
      $ret = /** call parent's method to_s() */
    }
    return $ret;
  }

}
```

How to call parents method which is overloaded in child? :) It is possible with static methods , but how to do it with non-static methods?

```
$a = new AChild();
$a->id = 1;
$a->name = 'Something';
echo $a; // Should echo "Something"

$b = new AChild();
$b->id = 2;
echo $b; // Should echo "2"
```

Comment: A side note: you could move `public $id;` declaration to the `AParent` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$ret = parent::to_s()`, it is enough